# loose, untaxed cigarettes -- what does "loose" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/police-2-nyc-cops-shot-car-critically-injured-212302732.html):

> The shooting comes at a tense time. Police in New York are being criticized for their tactics following the chokehold death of Eric Garner, who was stopped by police on suspicion of selling **loose**, untaxed cigarettes. Amateur video captured an officer wrapping his arm around Garner's neck and wrestling him to the ground. Garner was heard gasping, "I can't breathe" before he loses consciousness and later dies.

What does **loose cigarettes** really mean?

Comment: Individual cigarettes, taken out of their packet.

Comment: It is as @Stoney says. Definition 2 in [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/loose), or Definition 4 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loose).

Comment: The close votes on this question are misguided. This is a classic case of *EXOPHORIC REFERENCE* where native speakers or teachers don't get why learners don't understand something - because they take their own extra linguistic knowledge of their world (for example, cultural aspects) for granted. If you don't know what 'loose cigarettes' are, they could be loose as in not regulated, loose as in loosely packed with tobacco, loose as in immoral (perhaps with cannabis in), so on and so forth. This question should be left open!

Comment: @Araucaria perhaps the close votes were a knee-jerk reaction due to the fact that this user constantly asks for word meanings without bothering to report on the research he has done before posting the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means **individually sold cigarettes** which have been taken out of their pack.

Where I'm from, and I think in much of the US, they sometimes go by *looseys* and it is illegal to sell them. Some little shops do anyway.